# Gulp Task Order - Serial & Parallel

Tags: gulp, run-sequence

I've got the following tasks that are being ran by Gulp.

1. `script-a`
2. `script-b`
3. `script-c`

`script-a` is unrelated (relatively speaking) to tasks `b` and `c`, and takes around 5 seconds to run.

`script-b` and `script-c` are related so have to be ran in serial, and take around a second each to run.

Therefore, I want to be able to run `a` in parallel with `b` and `c` - while maintaining the latter two in serial.

I'm currently using runSequence to run them all in series;

```
gulp.task('script', function(callback) {
  return runSequence(
    'script-a',
    'script-b',
    'script-c',
    callback
  )
});
```

I can get `script-a` to run in parallel with *one* of the other tasks like so;

```
gulp.task('script', function(callback) {
  return runSequence(
    ['script-a', 'script-b'],
    'script-c',
    callback
  )
});
```

But that seems to be only half solving the problem. Seems like the answer should be obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try grouping script-b and script-c in another task and then run parallel in the task `script`. Something like this:

```
// script-b and script-c run in serial
gulp.task('scriptsBC', function(callback){
  return runSequence(
    'script-b',
    'script-c',
    callback
  )
})

// script-a and scriptBC run in paralell
gulp.task('script', function(callback) {
  return runSequence(
    ['script-a','scriptsBC'],
    callback
  )
});
```

Comment: It seems like overkill to create _another_ task to achieve what I'm after, but you might be right and it might be the only way to do it. Which is a shame!

Comment: Yea. Looks like not the better solution, but effective.

Comment: You can explore the version 4 of Gulp which already have two methods in it's API called [gulp.serial and gulp.paralell](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/) . But Gulp 4 it's not already finished, it's [just a tree in the gulp repository](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/tree/4.0)

Comment: Yes I'd looked through those changes - however I was wanting to stick to the stable version of Gulp - even if it means altering my tasks when 4 is finally released.